# Powershell - Listing failed IP addresses from security log including count

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell to output a list of IP addresses for failed logon events:

```
$DT = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1) # check only last 24 hours

$l = Get-EventLog -LogName 'Security' -InstanceId 4625 -After $DT | Select-Object @{n='IpAddress';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-2]} }
$g = $l | group-object -property IpAddress  | where {$_.Count -gt 20} | Select -property Name | export-csv c:\users\export.csv
```

I'd really like to improve it so it outputs the IP address like it is now, plus the $_.Count. I've tried a few things but I think I'm stuck in SQL world!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is, in the second pipeline, replace

```
Select -property Name
```

with

```
Select -property Name, Count
```

(But I would check by looking at the properties on the objects returned from the `group-object` with `get-member` first.)